# How to do Delayed Replication on MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, database-mirroring

I made replication for MySQL 8 just like in the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html
But I cant make a  17.4.11 Delayed Replication. I suppose before it was easy: 17.3.10 Delayed Replication, before you just need to change CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_DELAY = N; and that is all.
Can someone help me understand how to do Delayed Replication on MySQL 8?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stop slave;

change master to MASTER_DELAY=60;

start slave;

Comment: Thank you, dogs-cute! I just want to ask: should I query like you wrote: change master to MASTER_DELAY=60; OR should I write all the way with my last MASTER options and add your line like this: CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST = 'host_name',
MASTER_USER = 'user_name',
MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password'',
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'source_log_name',
ASTER_LOG_POS = source_log_pos,
MASTER_DELAY=60;

Comment: @mikehengetech There is no clear rule about this. It can be simultaneous or separate. I'm used to setting up the master-slave first and then turning on delayed replication, so that I can test whether my master-slave environment is correct first.

Comment: By the way, here is GREAT article on MySQL Mirroring: https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-master-master-replication-setup-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: Once again, thank you dogs Cute for your input, I do appreciate it!)